# TypeScript comes down with JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, iis, jasmine, typescript1.8

Been struggling with something and I can't find any specific information around this.

I have an application, I'm trying to unit test (Jasmine), but for some reason, the testing project brings down the TS files alongside the generated JS, which is causing some unexpected behaviour:

[image]

I figured it has something to do with they way I'm building up the spec runner page, in my case, I wrote a back-end method that loads the necessary JS files from the project I am testing, and adding the references to the JS files to a section on the site, designated for this.

the files are added using their web URL, and not the physical location on the server, for example:

```
http://directives/Tests.js
```

Is there a way to stop IIS from bringing down the TS files as well?